# Sitecore multivariate testing: how are values calculated?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I've created a multivariate test, but the values are stuck at zero. To make these values go up in accordance with my users' behavior when they convert, I have to do something I haven't done yet, and no documentation I can find describes just what this is.

I've tried configuring a goal with a rule of "item ID is equal to (some goal page's item ID)" and set the points value to eg. 1 or 5. But when I visit the page in a browser, the values on my test stay stuck stubbornly on zero.

Is there something I'm not doing?

Comment: It should be determined by the points in the goals etc. I had it working on my machine :) Anyway. Make sure you have published everything and check in the DMS database, that the goals get registered in the PageEvents table.

Comment: To which items did you set the points value? it should be to items referenced by the variations items, and make sure everything is published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the Test Statistics cache. It is set by default to 1 hour expiration time. To see your results instantly simply change the setting in the web.config to:

`<setting name="WebEdit.TestStatisticsCacheExpiration" value="00:00:00" />`

Comment: I no longer work with Sitecore but still pretty confident that would've been the cause. Thanks!